# Does a God's own mana cost count towards its own devotion?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm quite new to playing MtG, and had a question about [Erebos, God of the Dead](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErebos%2c%20God%20of%20the%20Dead%5d). It needs five devotion (5 black mana symbols on permanents on your field) to be a creature. Does the 1 black mana symbol on that card count toward my devotion to black? My friends and I were unsure.

Comment: The answers indirectly point this out, but there's no separate notion of devotion for Erebos ("its own devotion" as you suggest in the title), just one number: *your* devotion to black.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To quote one of the rulings on Gatherer:

> If a God enters the battlefield, your devotion to its color (including
>   the mana symbols in the mana cost of the God itself) will determine if
>   a creature entered the battlefield or not, for abilities that trigger
>   whenever a creature enters the battlefield.

Also from the rules:

> 700.5. A player’s devotion to [color] is equal to the number of mana symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents that player
>   controls. A player’s devotion to [color 1] and [color 2] is equal to
>   the number of mana symbols among the mana costs of permanents that
>   player controls that are [color 1], [color 2], or both colors.

Since the god is a permenant, it's mana symbols in it's casting cost count towards your devotion.

Answer (score 4):

As long as [Erebos, God of the Dead](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Erebos%2C%20God%20of%20the%20Dead), or any other card, is on the battlefield, it counts towards your devotion.

> 700.5. A player’s devotion to [color] is equal to the number of mana symbols of that color among the mana costs of permanents that player controls.

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.